# Rails - confused by URL change when model validations fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a User resource where `:name` is a required attribute on the model.

If I try to create a new user *without* a name, then the validation fails and the error messages are displayed at the top of the form as expected, **but** the URL of the page changes from `/users/new`, to `/users`?

I hadn't noticed this behaviour until tonight when I started playing around with capybara for the first time, and was expecting the current_path after a validation failure to be http://localhost:3000/users/new

I couldn't figure out why my spec was failing:

```
it 'should not create an invalid user' do
  fill_in "Name", :with=>""
  click_button "Create User"
  current_path.should == new_users_path
end
```

I've verified that it happens in all my other rails apps, so I realise this is the way rails works, but I really don't get what's going on here. Why does it work like this? Why does the path change from `new_users_path` to `users_path` when validations fail?

This has confused me immensely

Comment: What does your controller code for those actions look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly normal.

In a basic CRUD, you're creating your users using a `POST` request to `/users`.

If validation fails, you just render the `edit` view, but it doesn't change the url.

To change the url, you should `redirect_to` but, this way you'd loose the info related to the performed validation.

Comment: ahh, I get it now. Thanks, that explains it

Comment: IMHO this is a case where Rails' love of CRUD has trumped usability. Beyond the url change, what if the user refreshes the page after the validation error? Routing error because you are GETing from /users instead of /users/new. But good to know this is the accepted convention nonetheless (even if well known rails shops like square don't follow it: try forcing a validation error here https://squareup.com/login)

Comment: I should clarify that refreshing after a validation error would render the index view. but still confusing - the url for showing errors for a validation should be the same as the url for filling out the form - or at least I believe that would provide a better user experience.

Comment: @KarlRosaen: simply adapt your routes

Comment: Yes, just pointing out that the default recommended approach by the rails guides and what is created by 'rails generate scaffold' is, as the original question points out, kind of confusing for form validation.